# max-height for select element dropdown (option elements)

Tags: html, css

How do I limit the height of the dropdown of a select element - so that if the total amount of options is greater than this height - I should get a scroll in the dropdown.
I'd be satisfied if I could do this in terms of pixels or number of items.

So say I had the following html markup:

```
<select>
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
</select>
```

How would I display only say the first 4 options and the rest within a scroll.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/fbdHE/) is what I have so far, and it's not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching around on StackOverflow, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown). Sadly enough, if you want to keep it a dropdown-box, you cannot achieve what you want in CSS. JavaScript or jQuery will do the trick, as said in the link, or you could use the `size` attribute on your `select` tag, but this will break the dropdown-box look.

Comment: Yes, After adding `size` like `size=5` the select box opened for 5 options. But It breaks select box looks.

Answer (score -3):

I found the answer in CSS+HTML, you can do this way:

```
<select>
  <optgroup style="max-height: 65px;" label="">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Just tried this out, but it doesn't seem to work. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7VCng/)  out.

Comment: im using firefox and here it worked, change the max-height to 65px to get just the first 4 options

Comment: hmm seems to work just in firefox... the problem is the css property max-height that dont works fine in all browsers

Comment: i found the problem: its the style that dont apply on <optgroup> in another browsers just in firefox... im checking this out