# Set height for select

Tags: html, css

How set height for select? i need that "select" it height less popup height.
I found some more  solution with use js but this code is bad.
[image]

Comment: **[Please share your code with us](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, in russian: **[Как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: @AGE It is unnecessary

Comment: @iamnotmaynard attribute size in this case not work.

Comment: Right, I get what you mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/570642/1046690)

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I want the drop-down list does not extend outside the popup window. You understand me?

Comment: @AGE this not duplicate. Top answer in "http://stackoverflow.com/q/570642/1046690" is obsolete. Link to JSFiddle is corrupted

Comment: @KonstantinKulakov  updated my answer

Comment: @AhmadAlfy test it please https://jsfiddle.net/dLbtxj0v/

Comment: It's not possible using a regular <select> it's an OS level component. You would have to use a custom select, which wouldn't be worth it in my opinion.

Comment: @KonstantinKulakov the reason why I believe it is a duplicate is because adding `size` to the select box will eliminate the drop down, if you want to have a drop down and a custom height on it, you need to develop your own custom select element... which is exactly what **jlbruno** wrote at the same time I wrote this.

Comment: @AGE I was his last answer, I showed the result of adding size. It does not correspond to my expectations

Comment: Try the second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362484/max-height-for-select-element-dropdown-option-elements/13362562#13362562). See https://jsfiddle.net/fdqfytsr/ and adjust to taste.

Comment: @KonstantinKulakov one approach to doing your own custom select box is to use jQuery UI as shown in this example: **[How do you set the max height of an expanded “Chosen” element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21111652/1046690)**

Comment: @AGE Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @KonstantinKulakov no problem, I will post it as an answer

Comment: Why isn't [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/570642/1529630) a dupe? It says "Can someone confirm that its not possible to change the height of a dropdown". The answer says: "confirmed".

Comment: @Oriol because it is a known fact, perhaps not obvious but it is true if you take a quick look at the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all understand that native `select` when expanded is controlled by the web browser, therefore any and all modifications are out of your control.

That being said, you can create your own custom select elements and behavior. One such was is using JQuery UI as specified on this Stack Overflow question: **[How do you set the max height of an expanded “Chosen” element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21111652/1046690)**

For reference on why the native `select` element behaves the way it does, check this out: **[Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/570642/1046690)**

Any more questions regarding this? Please ask in the comments below.

Comment: [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/) is a very good option. I use it on many projects, and always have full control.. height width full colors etc..