# How to Limit the option size within 10

Tags: javascript, css

this is my current code that i used to display dropdown option.

```html
<select id="NotificationDate" style="display: table-cell; border-radius: 0.3em; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); outline: currentcolor none medium; box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px 1px 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, Tahoma; width: 215px; height: 20px; border: 1px none; background: lightblue none repeat scroll 0% 0%; margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
  <option value="2020/02/19">2020/02/19</option>
  <option value="2019/10/23">2019/10/23</option>
  <option value="2019/08/14">2019/08/14</option>
  <option value="2019/07/11">2019/07/11</option>
  <option value="2019/06/17">2019/06/17</option>
  <option value="2019/05/16">2019/05/16</option>
  <option value="2019/04/11">2019/04/11</option>
  <option value="2019/03/18">2019/03/18</option>
  <option value="2019/02/11">2019/02/11</option>
  <option value="2019/01/30">2019/01/30</option>
  <option value="2018/12/20">2018/12/20</option>
  <option value="2018/11/19">2018/11/19</option>
  <option value="2018/10/17">2018/10/17</option>
  <option value="2018/09/14">2018/09/14</option>
  <option value="2018/08/14">2018/08/14</option>
  <option value="2018/07/18">2018/07/18</option>
  <option value="2018/06/22">2018/06/22</option>
  <option value="2018/05/14">2018/05/14</option>
  <option value="2018/04/11">2018/04/11</option>
  <option value="2018/03/12">2018/03/12</option>
  <option value="2018/02/19">2018/02/19</option>
  <option value="2018/01/11">2018/01/11</option>
  <option value="2017/12/13">2017/12/13</option>
  <option value="2017/11/14">2017/11/14</option>
  <option value="2017/10/11">2017/10/11</option>
  <option value="2017/09/19">2017/09/19</option>
  <option value="2017/08/14">2017/08/14</option>
  <option value="2017/07/13">2017/07/13</option>
  <option value="2017/06/12">2017/06/12</option>
  <option value="2017/05/11">2017/05/11</option>
  <option value="2017/04/13">2017/04/13</option>
  <option value="2017/03/13">2017/03/13</option>
  <option value="2017/02/15">2017/02/15</option>
  <option value="2017/01/11">2017/01/11</option>
  <option value="2016/12/14">2016/12/14</option>
  <option value="2016/11/11">2016/11/11</option>
  <option value="2016/10/11">2016/10/11</option>
  <option value="2016/09/13">2016/09/13</option>
  <option value="2016/08/11">2016/08/11</option>
  <option value="2016/07/11">2016/07/11</option>
  <option value="2016/06/13">2016/06/13</option>
  <option value="2016/04/11">2016/04/11</option>
  <option value="2016/03/11">2016/03/11</option>
  <option value="2016/02/11">2016/02/11</option>
  <option value="2016/01/11">2016/01/11</option>
  <option value="2015/12/17">2015/12/17</option>
  <option value="2015/11/11">2015/11/11</option>
  <option value="2015/10/12">2015/10/12</option>
  <option value="2015/09/11">2015/09/11</option>
  <option value="2015/08/11">2015/08/11</option>
  <option value="2015/07/14">2015/07/14</option>
  <option value="2015/06/11">2015/06/11</option>
  <option value="2015/05/13">2015/05/13</option>
  <option value="2015/04/13">2015/04/13</option>
  <option value="2015/03/11">2015/03/11</option>
  <option value="2015/02/11">2015/02/11</option>
  <option value="2015/01/12">2015/01/12</option>
  <option value="2014/12/16">2014/12/16</option>
  <option value="2014/12/11">2014/12/11</option>
  <option value="2014/11/11">2014/11/11</option>
  <option value="2014/10/14">2014/10/14</option>
  <option value="2014/09/18">2014/09/18</option>
  <option value="2014/09/15">2014/09/15</option>
  <option value="2014/08/13">2014/08/13</option>
  <option value="2014/07/15">2014/07/15</option>
</select>
```

you can see in the image,the list is going too long.i want it should display only 10 and remaining should be like scroll and select.

[[image: 1]]

Comment: Please share the HTML code as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Set Height for the Drop Down of Select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534440/how-to-set-height-for-the-drop-down-of-select-box)

Comment: please visit this link your question already answered "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362484/max-height-for-select-element-dropdown-option-elements/13362562"

Comment: `<select size="3"></select>` source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534569/8508777) answer:

```html
<select onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;' 
        onchange='this.blur();'>
  <option>option a</option>
  <option>option b</option>
  <option>option c</option>
  <option>option d</option>
  <option>option e</option>
  <option>option f</option>
  <option>option g</option>
  <option>option h</option>
  <option>option i</option>
  <option>option j</option>
  <option>option k</option>
  <option>option l</option>
  <option>option m</option>
  <option>option n</option>
  <option>option o</option>
  <option>option p</option>
  <option>option q</option>
  <option>option r</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you explain where did it limited to 10? it shows all the list.

Comment: it's show all the options, but no more then 10 at once. for see all you have to scroll. it is the requirements, as I know

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<div class="container">
  <select  onfocus='this.size=10;' 
onblur='this.size=1;' 
onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
  <option value="">1 abc</option>
  <option value="">2 abc</option>
  <option value="">3 abc</option>
  <option value="">4 abc</option>
  <option value="">5 abc</option>
  <option value="">6 abc</option>
  <option value="">7 abc</option>
  <option value="">8 abc</option>
  <option value="">9 abc</option>
  <option value="">10 abc</option>
  <option value="">11 abc</option>
  <option value="">12 abc</option>
  <option value="">13 abc</option>
  <option value="">14 abc</option>
  <option value="">15 abc</option>
  <option value="">16 abc</option>
  <option value="">17 abc</option>
  <option value="">18 abc</option>
  <option value="">19 abc</option>
  <option value="">20 abc</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply it worked me.

Comment: Ok great. You can mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

push the date variables in an array, iterate through them in a for loop and in the body of the for loop, set the scroll box elements to the last ten of the array from getting size minus 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
             <option value="1">This is select number 1</option>
             <option value="2">This is select number 2</option>
             <option value="3">This is select number 3</option>
             <option value="4">This is select number 4</option>
             <option value="5">This is select number 5</option>
             <option value="6">This is select number 6</option>
             <option value="7">This is select number 7</option>
             <option value="8">This is select number 8</option>
             <option value="9">This is select number 9</option>
             <option value="10">This is select number 10</option>
             <option value="11">This is select number 11</option>
             <option value="12">This is select number 12</option>
           </select>
```