# Html drop down box with scrollbar at options

Tags: html, combobox, scrollbar

I've been trying to find a solution and example for this problem for a while now.

We have a combobox with a lot of options, ranging from 1 up to atleast 100.

Our customers don't always use proper resolutions so for some the options will scroll out of the screen.

**What we want is to have the normal HTML combobox but when you click it show a "box" which shows only 10 options with a scrollbar to scroll to the other 90 options**

Example:

[image: Example]

This example is (probably) made in winforms but I want to have this as a html/javascript(jquery). At which point the options will not be visible unless you click the control (As a normal combobox would work)

**Attempts**
I have already:
- tried putting the combobox in divs and giving it a size. But that will make it loose the popup function and we want to keep that.

- tried every other post in stackoverflow that concerned combobox's (dropdownbox) with vertical scrollbars
- added "size='5'" but this would just make it a listbox instead of a combobox
- added "multiple='yes'" but this doesn't do anything usefull for my cause

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
     <option value="1">This is select number 1</option>
     <option value="2">This is select number 2</option>
     <option value="3">This is select number 3</option>
     <option value="4">This is select number 4</option>
     <option value="5">This is select number 5</option>
     <option value="6">This is select number 6</option>
     <option value="7">This is select number 7</option>
     <option value="8">This is select number 8</option>
     <option value="9">This is select number 9</option>
     <option value="10">This is select number 10</option>
     <option value="11">This is select number 11</option>
     <option value="12">This is select number 12</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure if I'm getting it, but is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown) what you are looking for: you could just set the size of the select item which is generated.

Comment: As I said, and the example shows.  I want it to show ONLY the selected option, with a arrow down next to it. When you click it I want it to show the options with the scrollbar.  Your example lacks the original selected option box

Comment: Selecting an option from this "select" is explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_selected.asp

Answer (score -1):

Add this line of style in your component: style="height: 200px; width: 300px;".

.
.
.