# jQuery selectmenu dropdown height

Tags: jquery, select-menu

I want to limit the number of items in a dropdown list, lets say to 6. After quite a search I can't find anything other than a hint there is a maxHeight option, but that appears to have no effect.

HTML:

```
<label for="files">Select a file:</label>
<select name="files" id="files">
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
// configure
$( "#files" ).selectmenu({
              icons: { button: "ui-icon-search" } ,
              style: 'dropdown',
              maxHeight: 60
           });
// Test data
for( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
   $('#files').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: "a" + i,
        text : "b" + i
    }));
}
```

TTFN,
   Jon

[Edit] Just to clarify, I want to keep all the items in the droplist, only display a subset of them that the user scrolls through like a combobox in a normal deskop application.

Comment: The sipler, the better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8788381/2375207 just use size attribute

Comment: Another usful link (you should hang on sometimes there) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp

Comment: if you want to restrict the number of elements in the select, you may play around with css. Or js by removing the nth-child >6

Comment: @nicolallias, The 'size' attribute applies to the standard html select. However the jQuery selectmenu implementation ignores the attribute'

Answer (score 12):

You can also extend the CSS class of ".ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu" like this:

```
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu {max-height: 200px;}
```

> Note: Add this code in separate css file other than the downloaded css
>   library of jqueryUI.

Comment: for my case ```.ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown { height: auto !important; }``` suited me

Answer (score 10):

First you need to include menuWidget method. And then add class with limited height value.
JS code

```
$( "#files" )
  .selectmenu()
  .selectmenu("menuWidget")
  .addClass("overflow");
```

and CSS

```
.overflow { height: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: limiting a list to a certain number of element in jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/8dgc6jrr/

```
var LIMIT = 4; // limit to the fourth element
$("option").each(function( index, object ) {
    if(index+1>LIMIT){
        object.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Re-reading my post I think I have phrased it wrongly, D'oh. I mean I want to keep all the items in the dropdown, ony show a subset of them that the user can scroll thorugh.

Comment: Ooooh indeed, I suppose you have to play around vith css :/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added css code for each menu I wanted height to be changed:

```
CSS:
#yourMenuID-menu {
  max-height: 300px;
}

HTML:
<select id="yourMenuID" size="6" class="form-control">
  <option value="" selected>All</option>
</select>
```

"-menu" is added by jQuery UI to each menu (select tag in my case).