# html select dropdown scrollbar - ONLY when drop box present

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to place a scrollbar inside an html 'select' and 'option' area? I only want the scrollbar to appear when the dropdown menu is clicked. I have set max-height and overflow's appropriately (at least according to Google search result articles and Stackoverflow responses) but nothing seems to change. I do not want the max-height or height to effect the loaded size.

```
<div class="medium-6 large-6 columns view-value1">
        <table id="period-picker">
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" id="BtnPreviousPeriod" class="gray-button" onclick="previousPeriod()">«</button></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="TimePeriod" class="gray-button button dropdown" onchange="updatePeriodButtons()">
                            <option value="08-16-2014">Aug-16-2014</option>
                            <option value="08-01-2014">Aug-01-2014</option>
                            <option value="07-16-2014">Jul-16-2014</option>
                            <option value="07-01-2014">Jul-01-2014</option>
                            <option value="06-16-2014">Jun-16-2014</option>
                            <option value="06-01-2014">Jun-01-2014</option>
                            <option value="05-16-2014">May-16-2014</option>
                            <option value="05-01-2014">May-01-2014</option>
                            <option value="04-16-2014">Apr-16-2014</option>
                            <option value="04-01-2014">Apr-01-2014</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><button type="button" disabled id="BtnNextPeriod" class="gray-button" onclick="nextPeriod()">»</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

is what I have so far. I eventually want to set it to where the scroll bar appears and only 5-8 options are shown before having to scroll down. does it have anything to do with it being a table row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I limit the visible options in an HTML <select> dropdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown) on StackOverflow. As mentionned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8788691/3956967 you can't do that with a `select` element but you can use javascript to replace it with a fake select and dropdown.

Comment: it works well, along with another JFiddle example, but when I apply these similar changes, The absolute positioning pushes all other items up and down. I may have to just start fiddling with that