# How to set the height or the visible options number in a select tag?

Tags: html, select

I have a select tag which has 100 options. 
So when I click in the select, the select displays 20 or 30 options by default (but you can see the other options with the scrollbar of the options list).

Now, I want the select make visible only 10 options for example instead of 20 or 30. If no, try to decrease the height of the options list.

The size="10" attribut don't suit because the select displays immediately 10 options when you don't click the select. I just want the select display 10 options WHEN you click the select.

So is it possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aTzc2/188/

```
 <select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>10){this.size=10;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
```

For reference, [How can I limit the visible options in an HTML <select> dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown)

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem ! It's what I looked for !