# Limiting options in select dropdown to a specific number

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, user-interaction

I have a dropdown list, of the options in dropdown list is less than or equal to 10 this will display all the available options but if the number of options is more than 10 then the options list should have a vertical scroll bar.

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit the visible options in an HTML <select> dropdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HTML Code

```
<select onmousedown="if(this.options.length>15){this.size=15;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 <option>6</option>
 <option>7</option>
 <option>8</option>
 <option>9</option>
 <option>10</option>
 <option>11</option>
 <option>12</option>
 <option>13</option>
 <option>14</option>
 <option>15</option>
 <option>16</option>
 <option>17</option>
 <option>18</option>
 <option>19</option>
 <option>20</option>
 <option>21</option>
 <option>22</option>
 <option>23</option>
 <option>24</option>
 <option>25</option>
</select>
```

Please check the working fiddle:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhatnagar018/dmf9udk7/)

Answer (score 0):

As gcampbell noted, this is the job of the browser and cannot be influenced. If you want it to style, you have to create your own menu.
For example:

```
<div id="menu">
<p>1</p>
...
</div>

p{height:10px}
#menu{height:100px;overflow:scroll;}
```