# Change the Size of a Bootstrap Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple html select box with a lots of options (round about 100).
Because the select box has so much options, it uses the complete desktop height for showing the options, but I want to add a scrollbar and only show 5 options at the same time.

the size attribute doesent work for me.

This is my code:

```html
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<Select id="selectUser" onchange="" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="margin-top: -3px; background-color: white; height: 30px;" >
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown

Comment: Thank you for the link but it doesent helped me. i think the problem is because the dropdown-toggle class..

Comment: you can always customize a dropdown with CSS. see some examples here - https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=dropdowns&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Answer (score 0):

As I know **you can not change the `height` of `select`** because it browser definition

See here why option can not be changed:https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

See here sizes of option in browsers:[Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

**However you can set `size` to `select`**

```css
select{
margin-top: -3px;
background-color: white;
height: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">
<select class="form-control" id="selectUser" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i just want to be able to use the size html attribute. this would be enough.

Comment: This works, but the style is very ugly. the drop down menu should be beautiful, if u know what i mean. this is why i use bootstrap. But thanks for your help.

Comment: This works for me! thank your for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: really appricate if you mark as answer :) have a nice day too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

`#selectUser {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}`