# How to adjust the number of lines in the scroll area, for example, only show 10 lines in the select tag

Tags: html, css

[image: Picture]

I added the size = 10 attribute in  tag but that is not what I need

```
  <select size=10>
```

Comment: this Q answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit the visible options in an HTML <select> dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown)