# <select> dropdown list cutting off when limiting visible options

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a select dropdown menu containing a list of states. I have restricted the visible options after clicking the dropdown via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown) stackoverflow solution as can be seen in my code below:

```
        <div>
            <label asp-for="Venture.Location" class="form-label">Venture Location</label>
            <select asp-for="Venture.Location" class="form-input form-select" required onmousedown="this.size=9" onblur="this.size=0" onchange="this.size=0">
                <option disabled selected value="">select an option</option>
                @foreach(var location in Model.Locations)
                {
                    <option value="location">@location</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
```

However, clicking the dropdown, I will see a cuttoff option thus showing more than 9 options. How can I make sure to only show the correct amount of options via the size? How can I get rid of the cutoff option?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that the padding on the select element was causing the issue. I have removed padding once the `mousedown` event has occured.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (as it has been written inside of one of the comments of the answers you copied code from is that this crashes from IE11).

You can simply fix this with `size` attribute onto `select` tag:

```
<select id="vehicles" size="2" >
       <option value="Location1">Location1</option>
       <option value="Location2">Location2</option>
       <option value="Location3">Location3</option>
   </select>
```

This will result in showing only `Location1` and `Location2`

Answer (score -2):

Try to use in css

```
.form-input {
margin: 10px 0px;
padding: 15px;
overflow: auto; /* This option can helpyou!*/
}
```

Comment: Overflow should be used only when there is too much content to fit in a box and definitely not to solve this problem. When you use a value of overflow such as auto, you create a Block Formatting Context (BFC). The content of the box that you have changed the value of overflow for acquires a self-contained layout. Content outside the container cannot poke into the container, and nothing can poke out of that container into the surrounding layout. This will enable scrolling behavior, as all box content needs to be contained and not overlap, so this suggestion could end up in buggy interface.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).